# Reusing KStream object within same Kafka streams application to find count across multiple Time Windowes

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

Can I reuse the same KStreams object multiple times within a topology and create multiple time-windowed counts?

I have one Kafka Streams application, consuming one Kafka topic. I want to created count for multiple time windows (e.g. by minute, by hour).

I'm wondering if there is any issue with doing the following. I see that it works fine -- just wondering if a stream is supposed to be reused like that.

```
public void accept(KStream<MyKey, MyKey> myKeyStream,
                   GlobalKTable<String, String> globalTable) {

    myKeyStream.groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(1)).grace(Duration.ofMinutes(1)))
            .count(Materialized.<MyKey, Long, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(
                    "minute-store")
                    .withRetention(Duration.ofMinutes(1)))
            .toStream()
            .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(k.key(), v))
            .join(globalTable,
                    (MyKey k, Long v) -> k.getValue().toString(),
                    new ValueJoiner())
            .print(Printed.toSysOut());


    myKeyStream.groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofHour(1)).grace(Duration.ofHour(1)))
            .count(Materialized.<MyKey, Long, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(
                    "hour-store")
                    .withRetention(Duration.ofHour(1)))
            .toStream()
            .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(k.key(), v))
            .join(globalTable,
                    (MyKey k, Long v) -> k.getValue().toString(),
                    new ValueJoiner())
            .print(Printed.toSysOut());
}
```

Comment: Yes. That is totally correct usage. You can fan-out any `KStream` to as many downstream operators as you want and the data will be "broadcasted" accordingly.

Comment: great! Thank you @MatthiasJ.Sax. A related question that I asked is if the two groupings can be done in parallel (say in two separate CompletableFutures in Java). I believe that won't be the right usage as 1 stream tasks is supposed to be run in a single thread.

Comment: Yes, if  `groupByKey()` does not result in a repartitioning it would be one task.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax if you do that will all of the data be re-read from kafka for each stream re-use?

Comment: I you re-use the same `KStream` object and apply different downstream operators, the data will be read only once from the topic, and fed into both downstream operators.